# How can I start background service without notification?

Tags: android, firebase

I am working on a phone tracking application like google find my device. App starts on boot_completed but android wants it as a foreground service but this app  always listens firebase to take location request or ring phone triggers  and we dont want to show notification.It will be a system app and I am using this on a rooted phone.How can I start this service and listen database triggers momently without any notification? I am taking this error

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.appi.tracker.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.appi.tracker/.Services.MainService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{a76b66c u0a96 TRNB idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}`

Comment: You're going to have a hard time with this because Android might still kill your app's process in the face of resource contention with other apps. It won't matter if you have a service or not.  I suggest looking into FCM push notifications instead.

Comment: How can i use this sir ?  sending notification to all device or only the phone with token ? because i guess i need to store user tokens on realtime database i guess.it will be huge problem if we can not access phones when thieft or lost.

Comment: @sabe you need to store phone token in the database.